# bash - use exec for file descriptors using environment variables

Tags: bash, exec, flock

```
LOCK_FD=200
LOCK_FILE=/tmp/lock-file
exec ${LOCK_FD}>${LOCK_FILE}
```

I get an error

```
exec: 200 not found
```

This however works

```
LOCK_FD=200
LOCK_FILE=/tmp/lock-file
eval "exec ${LOCK_FD}>${LOCK_FILE}"
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methinks that's because redirection is performed before variable expansion. `man bash` is not quite clear which is done first:

> REDIRECTION
>          Before a command is executed, its input and output may be redirected . . .
>
> EXPANSION
>          Expansion  is performed on the command line after it has been split into words.

With the redirection done and removed, `exec` tries to execute `200` which doesn't exist, and thus the error msg.

Comment: ok thank you, I guess that explanation works.